# Grails: getting No Session in Promise.onComplete()

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, promise

Grails 3.2.9

After executing a task, the onComplete method cannot get a hibernate session.

Controller:

```
def addBranch() {
    Branch newBranch = new Branch(name: branchName, root: newBranchRoot, 'active':false).save();    
    Promise p = gitService.asyncPull(newBranch)     
    p.onComplete { b ->
        println "finished adding branch " + branchName;         
        newBranch.setActive(true);
        newBranch.save();  <<<=== EXCEEPTION THROWN HERE
    }       
    p.onError { Throwable err ->
        println "An error occurred ${err.message}"          
    }       
    respond(status:"ok", message:"success!");       
}
```

Service:

```
public Promise<Branch> asyncPull(Branch branch) {
    WebPromises.task {          
        initBranch(branch);
        pull (branch.name);
        branch;
    }
}
```

Exception Stack Trace

2017-05-23 13:41:29.123 [ead 6]ERROR Async execution error: Could not obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for c
urrent thread

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for c
urrent thread
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.getSession(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:317)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:273)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:230)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:116)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.UniqueConstraint.processValidate(UniqueConstraint.java:149)
        at grails.validation.AbstractConstraint.validate(AbstractConstraint.java:107)
        at grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty.validate(ConstrainedProperty.java:979)
        at org.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validatePropertyWithConstraint(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:206)
        at org.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validate(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:81)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:122)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save$11.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at com.care.incasa.Branch.save(Branch.groovy)
        at com.care.incasa.Branch.save(Branch.groovy)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$save$1.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at com.care.incasa.AdminController$_addBranch_closure1$$EQKTGeEk.doCall(AdminController.groovy:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReloadedTypeInvoker$2.invoke(ReloadedTypeInvoker.java:133)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1461)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at org.grails.plugins.web.async.AsyncWebRequestPromiseDecorator.invokeClosure(AsyncWebRequestPromiseDecorator.groovy:91)
        at org.grails.plugins.web.async.AsyncWebRequestPromiseDecorator$_decorate_closure2.doCall(AsyncWebRequestPromiseDecorator.groovy:67)
        at org.grails.plugins.web.async.AsyncWebRequestPromiseDecorator$_decorate_closure2.call(AsyncWebRequestPromiseDecorator.groovy)
        at org.grails.async.factory.gpars.GparsPromise$_onComplete_closure1.doCall(GparsPromise.groovy:92)
        at org.grails.async.factory.gpars.GparsPromise$_onComplete_closure1.call(GparsPromise.groovy)
        at groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataCallback$1.run(DataCallback.java:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsSessionContext.currentSession(GrailsSessionContext.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:688)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.getSession(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:315)
        ... 44 common frames omitted

Comment: Can you try getting the branch from DB again inside onComplete rather than using the copy created at start of method e.g. `def branch = Branch.get( newBranch.id )` then set active & save

Comment: This doesn't solve the specific problem you asked about, but in general a better practice is to move your transactional logic out of the controller and into a transactional service bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such cases you should be using `withTransaction` or `withSession` to handle the transactional context yourself:

```
p.onComplete { b ->
  Branch.withTransaction{
    println "finished adding branch $branchName"        
    newBranch.active = true
    newBranch.save()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, with the changes mentioned this works:

```
Promise<Branch> p = gitService.asyncPull(newBranch)     
p.onComplete { b ->
  Branch.withTransaction { session ->               
    Branch br = Branch.findByName(b.name);
    br.setActive(true);
    br.save(flush:true);
  }
}
```